# How to render and sort multiple different objects in same container in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have two different types of objects, say of classes Object1 and Object2. I want to be able to render, mix, and sort them in the same container.

In the controller action:

```
@objects1=Object1.reorder('created_at DESC')
@objects2=Object2.reorder('created_at DESC')
```

In the view:

```
 <div class="container">
   <%= render @objects1 %>
   <%= render @objects2 %>
 </div>
```

What SQL/ActiveRecord statement can I use so that they are sorted against one another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just combining them into a single array and then sorting the array?

```
@all_objects = objects1.concat(objects2).sort!{ |a,b| a.created_at <=> b.created_at }
```

Comment: You could also `.sort_by!(&:created_at)`.

Comment: Mu. Brilliant. Thanks! That is actually the only way I've found that sorts two different objects with attribute_alias'. The answer here and any other sort method fails.